# Core Data ManagedObject Subclass Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I am currently attempting to make a custom migration with removing an entity's relationship to become a subclass of the removed relationship

Heres what Version 1 looks like,

```
Entity : Product (NSManagedObject)
Relationship : ProductDetails (to-one)
```

Here are some properties of entity `Product` and `ProductDetails`

```
Product 
- itemNumber

ProductDetails
- description
- weight
```

Now I want to have `Product` be a subclass of `ProductDetails`

```
Entity : Product (ProductDetails)
Relationship : nil
```

I know I am supposed to implement a Mapping Model but haven't seen examples or documentation on this sort of problem.

The result of this migration should have all properties of `Product`'s relationship to `ProductDetails` mapped accordingly with no data loss.

Ex.

```
Product 
- itemNumber (value -> '001')
- description (value -> 'some description')
- weight (value -> 5)
```

Comment: Is the relationship one-to-one and does every product have a productDetails and does every productDetails have a product?

Comment: Product has a 'to-one' relationship to ProductDetails but there is no inverse, which there SHOULD be initially. So I am just attempting to make Product a subclass of ProductDetails, copy all values from ProductDetails to the Product, then remove the relationship. I am almost finished with the mapping model and implementation though and plan on posting my answer